# Error while creating SOAP client using CXF in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, cxf, java-ee-6

I am new to spring framework and this question may be a silly one. But please do provide a solution for this error.

I am getting following error while trying to run Spring MVC application which consumes SOAP based web-service using Apache CXF.

```
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 08, 2012 2:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Aug 08, 2012 2:09:29 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\rtProjectsWS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\dataservice-client\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.1.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Aug 08, 2012 2:09:29 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\rtProjectsWS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\dataservice-client\WEB-INF\lib\geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/rtProjectsWS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/dataservice-client/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/rtProjectsWS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/dataservice-client/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Aug 08, 2012 2:09:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 08, 2012 2:09:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerAdapter.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:159)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The steps I followed to create the project as follows:

1. Created Spring MVC Project by selecting MVC template in STS IDE.
2. Generated CXF SOAP Client using the wizard.
3. Modified spring config by adding following line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://markmail.org/message/g4rci3jvj4uglofw) post can help or [this](http://www.thecorneroffice.org/blog/plink/2009/02/090226-1759.html) . it basically says that you have a version conflict or an old version of slf4j.

Comment: Thanks you for your replay. Also I found that I am not able to use CXF, AXIS 2 and Java-WS it says WSDL is not valid. So I tried with axis and generated the proxies and I am using this with Spring MVC. It works .... :)